# Why put struct inside structure without reference name

Tags: c

I understand a nested structure like this:

```
struct student
{
    struct person
    {
        char name[20];
        int age;
        char dob[10];
    } p ;

    int rollno;
    float marks;
} stu;
```

You will see that the struct person will have a "p" inside for us to access the field. 
Example `stu.p.name` refers to the name of the person. But somehow, when I study the code below, I don't see the beauty/purpose of putting a struct inside the struct.

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t magic;                   /**< Filter duplicate packets */
    struct {
        bool transmit_self      : 1;  /**< Whether the forwarded packet is for yourself */
        bool transmit_all       : 1;  /**< Whether to send packages to all devices */
        size_t transmit_num     : 10; /**< Number of destination devices forwarded */
        size_t total_size_low   : 12; /**< Total length of the packet */
        uint8_t packet_seq      : 3;  /**< Serial number of the packet */
        size_t total_size_hight : 1;  /**< Total length of the packet */
        uint8_t compress_rate   : 4;  /**< The ratio of the data to the original after compression */
    };
    mwifi_data_type_t type;           /**< The type of data */
} __attribute__((packed)) mwifi_data_head_t;
```

I can change to this format without any problem:

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t magic;                   /**< Filter duplicate packets */

        bool transmit_self      : 1;  /**< Whether the forwarded packet is for yourself */
        bool transmit_all       : 1;  /**< Whether to send packages to all devices */
        size_t transmit_num     : 10; /**< Number of destination devices forwarded */
        size_t total_size_low   : 12; /**< Total length of the packet */
        uint8_t packet_seq      : 3;  /**< Serial number of the packet */
        size_t total_size_hight : 1;  /**< Total length of the packet */
        uint8_t compress_rate   : 4;  /**< The ratio of the data to the original after compression */

    mwifi_data_type_t type;           /**< The type of data */
} __attribute__((packed)) mwifi_data_head_t;
```

Compared to the original code, I didn't put a struct inside. Although the behavior would be same, I wish to know why they put the structure like that. My mind keeps asking "why?" Is it a good practice on coding or reserved for some purpose?

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with the "packed" attribute.  Perhaps there is some compiler out there in the wild that doesn't align mwifi_data_type properly (for say arm which can be pedantic about such things) or it was just the programmer's attempt to group all the bits together as a "word".  (Informal "documentation" if you will.)

Comment: @FrankMerrow Thanks for your info, I think the later part you describe is more make sense, it just the programmer attempt to group all. And can I conclude that actually not needed to put the struct ? It don't serve any purpose from my perspective

Comment: In the first example, in C (but not C++), you could use `struct person` outside the `struct student` type.  In the second case, there is no structure tag, so the structure type defined inside the tagless structure type with the typedef name `mwifi_data_head_t` cannot be used anywhere else.  Whether that's a good thing or not, and whether it was deliberate or not, is open to debate.  Be aware that most aspects of bit-fields are implementation defined — regardless of whether the set of bit-fields are inside a structure.  In particular, the mix of types could present issues on some systems.

Answer (score 2):

Using an "anonymous" struct like this allows somebody reading the code to understand that those fields are logically connected, and belong as a single unit. The fact that they are all bit fields that sum to 32 indicates that all those fields should be "thought of" as a single `uint32_t`, of which different bits represent different values.

You are correct that there is no (apparent) difference in behavior when the `struct` wrapper is removed. My guess is that it's purely for organization, or maybe as a remnant of a nested struct that *used to* have a name.

Comment: I got the same thought in mind, but let's wait for others see they got any opinion. By the way the original code is a library code from Espressif ESP32 driver. So I guess it may be written by some professional programmer that serve some meaningful purpose.